# Scope of using block on an external variable

Tags: c#, using-statement

What happens to the image in "rendered" once using block disposes "b"?

```
Bitmap rendered;

using(Bitmap b = new Bitmap(calcHeight, calcWidth))
{
   using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
   {
        RenderMyBitMap(ref b);
        rendered = b;
   }
}
//Outside Using block
DoSomeThingElseWith(rendered);
```

Comment: Why don't you give it a try and see for yourself?

Comment: Because there is still a reference to `b` it will not be garage collected.  When `rendered` is set to null, the next cycle of garage collection will take it away.

Comment: I did not see any error. Could not find if I am filling up memory (an OOM exception waiting to happen) or it is safe. Black Frog answer seems to be justified. But cannot check it.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `rendered` points to the same instance as `b`.  If you attempt to access it after the `using` block, you'll get an [ObjectDisposedException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.objectdisposedexception(v=vs.110).aspx), which is

> The exception that is thrown when an operation is performed on a disposed object.